# Different ffmpeg result after saving to png

Tags: python, image, video, ffmpeg, file-format

Saving images to PNG first seems to produce different ffmpeg encodes.  Running this test code

```
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import ffmpeg
import hashlib

ffmpeg.input('test.jpg').output('testff.png').run()
cv2.imwrite('testcv.png',cv2.imread('test.jpg'))
Image.open('test.jpg').save('testpil.png')

hashes=[]
for suf in ['.jpg','ff.png','cv.png','pil.png']:
    dest='test'+suf.replace('.','')+'.mp4'
    ffmpeg.input('test'+suf).output(dest).run()
    hashes.append(hashlib.file_digest(open(dest,'rb'),'md5').hexdigest())
    
print(hashes)
```

I get 
['a5b744a8ac0f6de9ec4de43ff737c46e'
,'ab62474f2160899e064ba24890047372'
,'baa788d5e4ef212ab610b8b5cf7772cb'
,'baa788d5e4ef212ab610b8b5cf7772cb']

As you can see, the only two that match are the cv2 and pillow conversions, and none of them match the original.  In terms of file size, the results that passed to png first seem to be about 10% smaller than the direct-from-jpg result.

Why is this happening and how can I avoid changing image data until I'm ready to encode?

Comment: It's unclear. What's the definition of "direct-from-jpg result"? What do you mean by "until I'm ready to encode"? Anyway the result of PNG encoder depends on the implementation of the encoder. Also, the result of JPEG decoder depends on the implementation of the decoder.

Comment: @relent95 The first result in my example is what I'm calling "direct-from-jpg".  I encode a video directly from a jpg source file without the intermediate step of saving as a png.  The results I'm talking about are the mp4 files, all encoded by ffmpeg with the default codec.

Comment: It's still unclear. What do you mean by "changing image data"? Do you now understand why the result mp4 files are not all equal? Consider the JPEG decoders of FFmpeg, OpenCV, and PIL. Output images from the second and third ones are equal, but the output image from the first one is different from them. It's well known that OpenCV does not correctly process a color profile in a JPEG file for example.